# Etymology of some personal pronouns in PIE

Tags: etymology, pronouns

In PIE we have the following traditionally reconstructed personal pronouns: ***u̯oe̯*** "you two" and ***u̯ei*** "we" (inclusive).

Brengtson claims that the original forms should be ***tu̯oe̯*** and ***tu̯ei*** respectively. He claims that ***tu̯oe̯*** is the dual number of the singular second-person promoun while ***tu̯ei*** is locative of it (meaning "I with/at you" -> we with you).

Is this theory solidly substantiated?

Comment: PIE had many dialects over a long period, and no doubt some of them had pronouns like that. It's important to bear in mind that there was never one PIE language, but rather a loose assemblage of dialects with related features. Thus, speaking of ***THE*** original forms, when dealing with unattested reconstructions, is taking liberties with the data. One should speak of possibilities, not origins.

Comment: Who is this 'Brengtson' you refer to? Perhaps you mean 'Bengtson'? Can you reference the location of that particular claim?

Comment: I'm not an Indo-Europeanist, but I'm curious where you get your 'traditionally reconstructed' forms from? I think **uei** is from Beekes but I didn't think he reconstructed duals (?) so I'm curious to know your source for **uoe** 'you two'.